# One LightBox button for Image, Video, and Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I have an Image, Video, and Text

I would like to have an the Lightbox present the respective (Image, Video, and Text)
when a Image, Video, and Text is clicked.

The items have an ids `#prw-item-2`
The image `id = #imagePreview`

```
<a id='imagePreview' class='fancybox' href='Penguins.jpg' 
data-fancybox-group='gallery' title='Image01'><img src='Penguins.jpg' 
alt='' height='180' width='310' style='margin: 5px'/></a>
```

The image `id = #videoPreview`

```
<iframe id='videoPreview' height='180' width='310' 
src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k'></iframe>
```

The image `id = #textPreview`

```
<textarea id='textPreview' class='form-control' rows='20' 
maxlength='500'>500 limit</textarea>
```

jQuery,
I am not sure, how to make 1 button,
switch between, item ids, and video/image/texts.

```
//LightBoxButtonPreview
var onClickCard = function(dst){    
var t = dst.id; //(t = item-2)
var q = '#prw-' + t; //(q = prw-item-2)
//(???) #imagePreview, #videoPreview, #textPreview
```

LightBox Button(???):

```
<a href="???" class="btn btn-default btn-primary fancybox" 
data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="ImagePreviewBtn">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> PreviewButton</a>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How you know what show with one button (PreviewButton) ? Or before need something select?

Comment: I have a lists of items that are images, videos, or texts,
but only one lightbox button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#preview-button", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _whatShow = $("#what-show").val();
    if (!_whatShow) return false;
    switch(_whatShow) {
        case 'image': _type ='inline'; _href='#imagePreview'; break;
        case 'video': _type ='iframe'; _href=$('#videoPreview').attr('src'); break;
        case 'text': _type ='inline'; _href='#textPreview'; break;
    }
   $.fancybox({
      href: _href,
      width: 730,
      height: 530,
      type: _type,
    }); 
});
```

**[Demo page](http://coding.kz/stack/fancybox/fancybox.html)**

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to implement! Thanks